# accessing unsigned integer values in fortran

Tags: integer, fortran, unsigned, fortran95, fortran2003

If I have a `c_int8_t` variable in Fortran and want to interpret the underlying bits as an unsigned integer (for indexing rather than for any arithmetic) what is the most efficient way to do the conversion? I want to do something like

```
X( some_function( my_c_int8_t_var ) ) = 1
```

where X is an array and `some_function` should return a c_int16_t containing the unsigned value of `my_c_int8_t_var`. I have seen options including transfer, iadd (or I guess just a simple conditional with a cast and an addition) but I would like to know what would be the most efficient way (this indexing is taking place in an inner loop). Of course it doesn't have to be a function - if it can be done with an inline expression that would be great.

EDIT: It would be nice if the approach would also work for other integer size... ie for getting the contents of unsigned c_int16_t in a c_int32_t and getting an unsigned c_int32_t into a c_int64_t.

Comment: Is it not possible to declare `X` using the full range of the signed integer, e.g. `integer, dimension(-huge(my_c_int8_t_var) : huge(my_c_int8_t_var)) :: X`? That would be much less hassle.

Comment: I see what you mean but in my case I am not using the full range - the user passes the maximum value and I allocate the X array accordingly (X(Xm) at the moment or X(0:(Xm-1)). I would like to be able to support the full range of unsigned ints though (so can get up to 256 without needing to go to 2byte data) - but never allocate more than necessary for the maximum value provided.

Comment: Oh, I see; I misunderstood the intent of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `transfer()` and `ichar()` functions. Something like

```
X(ichar(transfer(my_c_int8_t_var,"a")))) = 1
```

For example

```
 use iso_c_binding
 write (*,*) ichar(transfer(-1_c_int8_t,"a"))

 end
```

returns 255.

When you cannot find a coresponding character kind (e.g., 16bit) I would write a function that adds huge(1._my_integer_kind) to the value.

```
integer function indx(i)
  integer(c_int16_t),intent(in) :: i

  if (i<0) then
    indx = 2*(huge(i)+1) + i
  else
    indx = i
  end if
end function indx
```

or

```
  integer function indx2(i)
    integer(c_int8_t),intent(in) :: i

    indx2 = TRANSFER([i,0_c_int8_t],1_c_int16_t)
  end function indx2
```

This last case works only for little-endian platforms.

You can make a generic interface to this function.

```
 write (*,*) indx(-2_c_int16_t)
```

gives 65534

Comment: Thanks thats just the kind of trick I was looking for. But it seems specific to 8 bit case. I know that was my example but I was hoping to find something that would also work for getting an unsigned c_int16_t value into a c_int32_t etc.

Comment: Thanks - for the huge method - doesn't there need to be a conditional? For 'positive' values in the unsigned data I don't want to add anything, the addition should only happen if i<0? (Or am I confused?) so then I was worried about the conditional slowing things down since this is an inner loop?

Comment: I guess the alternative approach is to transfer to the larger type and then do a bitwise AND with an appropriate mask to zero the large bits but I was not sure how to sort that out - and also not sure if that would be slower than the addition with the conditional.

Comment: But with TRANSFER apparently "If the bitwise representation of the result is longer than that of SOURCE, then the leading bits of the result correspond to those of SOURCE and any trailing bits are filled arbitrarily." I am not sure which leading and trailing are (in terms of large or small parts of the bitwise value)...

Comment: With those tricks you have to be aware of differences between the little-endian and big-endian machines and resulting nonportability.

Comment: OK - but I am only ever using x86(-64) which is little-endian? So would something like IAND(TRANSFER(i,1_c_int32_t), int32(huge(i))+1) work? (I am not sure if the mask would be correct - or if it could be any faster than the one with the conditional...

Comment: Last note, the equivalence approach might be faster. It depends on the optimizations the compiler is able to do.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
integer(c_int16_t) :: i, i2(2)
integer(c_int32_t) :: i32

equivalence (i32, i2)

i2(2) = 0
```

then inside the loop

```
i2(1) = i
X(i32) = 1
```

Would this work? Should I put the 16 bit data in i2(1) or i2(2) for little-endian platform?

Comment: Yes, but I would write it like this, I was going to suggest you that TRANSFER([i,0_c_int8_t],1_c_int16_t)

Comment: TRANSFER([i,(0_c_int16_t)],1_c_int32_t)

Comment: Ah thats great... I didn't know you could mix arrays and scalars in transfer!